# How to use Firebase emulator to test Java cloud functions with Firestore trigger?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Java11 runtime for Google cloud/firebase functions, which was quite recently released. I want to test firestore trigger functions on my local machine. Guides on the internet seem to be using the command firebase functions:shell which by itself starts the required emulation processes. However, I don't find any method to specify the .jar file for the firebase functions:shell command. Or any way to specify the functions. I know it doesn't load my Java http function because it shows the loaded functions and helloWorld isn't one of them:

```
gintas-mac:functions gintas$ firebase functions:shell
⚠  Your requested "node" version "10" doesn't match your global version "8"
i  functions: Loaded functions: helloWorld
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services will affect production: firestore, database, pubsub
```

Comment: Firebase Functions only allows Nodejs as a runtime. One thing you could try is to use [Cloud Functions for the Java11 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/java-runtime) and take a look at the [Functions Framework for Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-java) to test them locally.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use the Firebase CLI to test a function written in Java.  Firebase only supports functions written with the firebase-functions module on nodejs.